# Adding Storyboard support in existing project

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uistoryboard

I am using this GitHub project for an application that I am working on ([Github Link  1](https://github.com/romaonthego/RESideMenu)). Unfortunately, this project doesn't support Storyboards. However, I did find one version with Storyboard support ([Github Link 2](https://github.com/zetachang/RESideMenuStoryboardDemo)) however, I was unable to get it to work with the suggestions that they made. Here are the results of the suggestions:

- **Subclass `RESideMenu` as `RootSideMenuViewController` do and set the initial scene's custom class as the one you created.**

When I tried this:

> ```
> RESideMenuItem *homeItem = [[RESideMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Home" action:^(RESideMenu *menu, RESideMenuItem *item)
> {
>     [menu hide];
>
>     UIViewController* vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainViewController"];
>     [menu displayContentController:vc];
> }];
> ```

When I tried it, I received an error saying:

```
Property 'storyboard' not found on object of type 'AppDelegate *'
```

- **Use Storyboard Id to instantiate a view controller. (`UIStoryboard – instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:`)**

Here is the code when I attempted to try it:

> ```
> RESideMenuItem *homeItem = [[RESideMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Home" action:^(RESideMenu *menu, RESideMenuItem *item)
>      {
>          [menu hide];
>
>          UIViewController* vc = [UIStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainViewController"]; [menu displayContentController:vc];
>      }];
> ```

When I tried this, I got an error message, saying:

```
No known class method for selector 'instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:'
```

The last one, I realized that it is already been done.

I have looked around Google to see if I could find anything, and found this:

```
UIStoryboard [instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainViewController"];
```

This didn't work either.

Sorry for the long post, but I'm not too sure what else I can do to fix this. Are there any other solutions? Did I overlook something? Please ask if I am not being clear on something.

For reference, I'm using Xcode 4.6.3. I am using Storyboards, and I am coding my project using ARC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to load the storyboard first:

```
[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboardName" bundle: nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SomeVCInMainStoryboard"];
```

Assuming that project is setup correctly, you should just need to change the names to load the Storyboard and a subsequent view controller.